# Using AJAX & jQuery to pull in certain HTML elements from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my first question on here so be nice!

I have a problem I just cant seem to get my head around......here it is.

I have a `<select>` list that I have populated using an external JSON file - which, for now is working a treat!

What I need to do now is pull in certain HTML elements from an external HTML file based on the selection made within the select menu.

For example if you visit - http://lddesigns.co.uk/Candidate/index.html, you will see that I have a select menu and also a few buttons I was playing around with, the options in the select menu are populated by JSON using jQuery (will post code below).

What I need to happen is...when an option in the menu is selected (e.g London) it needs to toggle a div within my page....pull in HTML from an external file and then display certain elements within that HTML file to make a 5 day weather forecast, I just cant seem to work out how this is done at all.

I have raw_html files for 3 of the 4 locations in the select list, when a user selects an option then it should pull in the relevant HTML - e.g for New York i have the HTML file nyc_weather.html.

I hope this makes sense and my HTML and jQuery code is below for you to ponder...I am a total jQuery, JSON, AJAX beginner and this is all new to me!

HTML:

```
<div id="weatherPod">

<h2>content</h2>

<select id="destinations" onchange="window.location=this.value;">
 <option value"">Select Destination</option>
</select>
<button id="button">Show</button>
<button id="button1">Div</button>

    <div id="weatherForecasts">

    <p>5 Day Forecast for [destinationID]</p>

    </div>  

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// The below function pulls in the data from the external JSON file

    $.getJSON('json/destinations.json', function (data) {

// attaches it to a variable
    var destinations = data.Destinations;

        $(destinations).each( function (id, destination) {
            $('select').append('<option value="raw_html/' + destination.destinationID +    
            '_weather.html">' + destination.destinationName + '</option>');
        }); 
    });

// Hide statements for our extra fields and also the weather forecast DIV
    $('#weatherForecasts').hide();
    $('#extraFields').hide();

    $("input[name='survey1']").change(function() {
        $("#extraFields").show("slow");
    });
    $("input[name='survey1']:checked").change(); //trigger correct state onload

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $('#weatherForecasts').load('raw_html/lon_weather.html .destinationWidth', function(){
    $('#weatherForecasts').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    });
});
```

That is all of my code, just incase there are any errors I am missing or anything!

Thanks Liam

Comment: It looks like you're already doing this with the call to the `.load()` function near the end of your code.  Is that not working in some way?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick reply....the .load() call does work but not in the way I need it to, that calls pulls in the file correctly through a button which I used for testing purposes, I need the select options to trigger the toggle of the HTML and also the file that is outputted within the DIV needs to be relevant to the users selection...for example if user selects London then the html file 'lon_weather.html' will display, if New York 'nyc_weather.html' will display....I hope that is a good enough explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your select element like this:

```
<select id="destinations">
   <option value"">Select Destination</option>
   <option value"nyc">New York</option>
   <option value"lnd">London</option>
   ...//according to your html file names 'nyc_weather.html'
</select>
```

and in your document.ready function

```
     $('#destinations').change(function(){
         if($(this).val().length > 0){
            var url = '/raw_html/'+ $(this).val() + '_weather.html'; // I assume your destination select option values are like 'nyc, lnd,...'

            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $('#weatherForecasts p').html(data);
                $('#weatherForecasts').slideToggle("slow");
            }).fail(function(){
                alert("file doesn't exist!");
            });
         }
         else{
            $('#weatherForecasts p').html("");
         } 
     });
```

and if your raw/html folder is in your website's root folder. it should work fine.

Comment: I have tried your code above Volkan, but it doesn't pull the right files in, sorry I am totally new to this so bare with me...my '_weather.html' files are in another directory called raw_html...is this why it is not working maybe?

Comment: again thanks for this mate, its the select options that need to do the magic though and not #button1 - sorry if I didn't make that clear bud...so depending on the users selection within the select menu, determines the ouputted HTML file.

Comment: OK bud, I fiddled with this and made it work....this is legendary...just need to work out how to spit out an error is someone selects an option that there isnt a file for, and also show blank when the first option is selected and we are laughing haha thanks mate, you are a legend!

Comment: i made some fix, according to your fix. but, really it's not legendary work. if it worked for you then vote up the answer or mark as answered.

Comment: just inserted your up to date code and im getting this error in console 'Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'fail'' :/

Comment: Trust me when your new to this and have been racking your brain for a while it is my friend! :D also I can 'Vote Up' because of my reputation or something, otherwise I would for sure!

Comment: thanks man, turns out my jquery version was old...whoops! it still doesn't work as expected though....have a look for yourself on the site...instead of alerting an error, what it does is displays the homepage of my portfolio site.... which is weird!

Comment: thats just the latest version of jquery that I downloaded the other day - that is strange!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you need something like this:

```
$('#destinations').change(function(){

  var selected = $(this).val();

  //perform AJAX request
  $.ajax({

     url:selected,
     type : 'GET'
     error: function(){},// handle error
     success: function(data){ 
         $('#weatherForecasts p').html(data); //put response data into html
     } //end of success function
  }); // end of ajax request

}); //end of change function
```

if you want to get a single element from the data maybe the right solution is to initialize a new jquery object.

```
var mydata = $(data); //initialize new jquery object
var myobject = $(data).find('#mytag'); // get a single element with id="mytag"
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for this, this does the magic for the select menu, it pulls in the HTML correctly etc :D however I only need certain data from the HTML file rather than all of it, is there a way to only pull in an id or certain tag from the HTML file like there is with .load() method?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...like I say I am new to this....how would this be put into the document and used? before the ajax request or after it? thanks

Comment: Just add it into the success function.

Comment: I am still not sure how this is done my friend... like I say it is very new to me and I am learning...but not as obvious to me as it would be to others! sorry